# Wordpress - Subdirectory - htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, subdirectory

I have Wordpress installed in a subdirectory:

```
/public_html/blog/
```

I want to be able to access the blog like this:

```
http://example.com/blog
```

and posts like this:

```
http://example.com/blog/category/postname
```

In general settings I have the "WordPress Address (URL)" set to:

```
http://example.com/blog
```

Permalinks is set like:

```
/blog/%category%/%postname%
```

In the subdirectory (/public_html/blog/) I have an .htaccess like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /blog/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /blog/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Everything works EXCEPT for being able to access the blog Home page at:
http://www.example.com/blog
Doing that sends me to the "Wordpress 404 page not found" page.

I'd be very grateful for a solution!

**EDIT**

I'm an idiot - I missed something vital. I needed to also change the Site URL in Wordpress > General to:

```
http://example.com/blog
```

Doing that and then removing /blog/ from the permalink structure made everything work. I probably wouldn't have spotted this if @IanB hadn't picked up the /blog/ bit not being necessary. Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2 things come to mind.
I don't think you need to add /blog/ in your permalink structure, (unless wordpress is adding that for you). That should be automatic if that is the file it is installed in.

Also,
Where is your index.php file for your wordpress install - Is it in the blog folder or in the /public_html/ folder.

If you want to display the blog at http://example.com/blog it should be in the blog folder.

What is the filepath you use to log in? Does that work fine?

Comment: Thanks for responding. I've tried lot's of combinations, so far what I posted above is the closest I've been to cracking it.

If I remove /blog/ from the permalink structure it doesn't work. I end up at example.com/category/postname.

index.php is in the blog directory - I do want to want to display the blog at example.com/blog (the rest of the site is bespoke and is in the root directory).

I can login all OK at example.com/blog/wp-admin.